# Can I use my MacBook display as a monitor for a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ssh, display

This question have been asked so many times, and every time the conversation switches to the SSH or VNS. Can I connect a Raspberry Pi (3 in my case) to the MacBook through the HDMI port and use the MacBook's display as a monitor for the Raspberry Pi?

PS: I know how to use SSH and VNS. I'm interested in this specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot. The HDMI port on a MacBook is only designed to **output** video. It isn't capable of receiving video **input**. This is standard practice and will be true of any standard laptop or even desktop on the market.